# how to make link to other partials in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to have a simple single page application with multi partial pages in mvc5. so i set a rout configuration and and controllers like what you see below. but my links doesnt working out and they dont show other partials in `<ng-view>`. and i know the cause of problem!...

when i click on the link from this route: `http://localhost:33087/CrudDemoApp.html#!/` its go to here: `http://localhost:33087/CrudDemoApp.html#!/#Test` and this url is wrong!! the correct url is this: `http://localhost:33087/CrudDemoApp.html#!/Test`
like you see it doesnt contain any `#` character!

when i enter correct url manually in address bar...its working on ! so ...

how can i erase this extra # in my links url????????

this is my app and route configuration:

```
var app2 = angular.module('customersApp', ['ngRoute']);

app2.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        controller: 'customersController',
        templateUrl: '/Partials/customers.html'
    }).
    when('/Test', {
        controller: 'customersController',
        templateUrl: '/Partials/Test.html'
    })


  .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });

}]);
```

and i set the container like this in my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Crud</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/Ang/app.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/Ang/controllers.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="customersApp">
<a href="#Test" >TestLink</a> //How to set this links href??
<ng-view>

</ng-view>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is right.

Can you please confirm me which version of angular.js and angular.route.js are you using? I can guess that you have used version 1.6 of angular js.

I will suggest please use angular.min.js version v1.5.11 and angular.route.js v1.4.1.

Comment: yeah i used 1.6..and i changed it to version 1.5.11...and i used 1.5.11 for angular.route.js...it worked on. TNX